# string manipulation in c#

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a string like this, that is some names separated by some backslashes:

```
string mainString = @"Sean\John\Rob\fred";
```

How can I get the last name in above string format, in this case "fred", while I want the name to be the last name in the string (after all backslashes)?

Thanks.

Comment: so what would be the final string look like?

Comment: WHat have you tried so far? If your totally lost maybe try split - http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-split .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

do you mean:

```
var list = mainString.Split('\\');
return list[list.Length-1];
```

Answer (score 9):

You could use LINQ to solve this:

```
string mainString = @"Sean\John\\Rob\fred";
var fred = mainString
   .Split("\\".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
   .Last();
```

You could also use `LastOrDefault()` to protect yourself against an empty string or a string that doesn't contain any `\`. Then `fred` would just be `null`.

Comment: This is the way to go. Declarative language is always simple and very readable.

Comment: @Josh: Do you really think that this is any more declarative/readable than using `Substring` and `LastIndexOf`? (It also allocates two arrays and four strings for no good reason.)

Comment: @LukeH: If I told you to give me the last name in a series of names separated by '\\', how would you do it? I would say, "split them by the separator and give me the last one." Declarative language is all about describing a problem in simple human terms and leaving it up to the compiler to figure out the details. If your problem does not require pristine performance, no one will care. Do you really think .Split().Last() is going to take that much longer to run? No.

Comment: The performance of Split vs Substring is 1285ms vs 47ms respectively of 1M iterations (ultra-scientifically performed test), so this is bad from that perspective. If we put the resource allocation aside for a minute, I believe the **most** expensive thing when it comes to software development are the mistakes we do. This method is pretty safe since it (if `LastOrDefault` is used) can handle a `mainString` without \ in it as well as an empty string while `Substring` would throw.

Comment: @MikeEast: The substring version doesn't throw. If there's no "\" in the string then the entire original string is returned. Whether, in that situation, the OP prefers null, the entire original string or something else entirely is up to them.

Comment: @LukeH: i meant to post earlier, but here goes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594505/string-manipulation-in-c/5594919#5594919

Comment: @LukeH, It doesn't throw, I see that now. The +1 to the rescue. I think this is a matter of taste and preference which means there's no way we can agree on what solution is the best. :) Next Question!

Answer (score 8):

First off, include a @in front of the string so that the \'s won't be considered as escape sequences:

```
string mainString = @"Sean\John\Rob\fred";
```

Then you can get your last name like this:

```
string lastname = mainString.Substring( mainString.LastIndexOf('\\')+1);
```

Note that this will give an exception if the string does not contain at least one \, so make a check to confirm that before trying to get the sub-string.

For long inputs, this should be faster than using `Split`, since you do not have to split the string into an array, when you know that you only need the last value anyway.

Comment: `LastIndexOf` will return -1 if the string doesn't contain \, so it won't throw an exception. `Substring( 0 )` will, in turn, return the entire `mainString` (which is probably what you'd want anyway :))

Comment: I really can't believe that this is not most upvoted answer. People are obsessed with linq and split.

Answer (score 3):

Using `Split` -- as most of the other answers have suggested -- is overkill in this situation and allocates a temporary array for no good reason. How about this instead?

```
string lastString = mainString.Substring(mainString.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
```

Comment: +1: `Substring` seems like the most performant variant here over `Split`.

Comment: @Josh: I also happen to think that it's more readable than most of the other answers. "Take the substring starting at one character beyond the last \ character". It's completely self-describing: the spec re-written as code.

Comment: So a lot of this comes down to how you phrase the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This could without any copying on optimized implementations:

```
        string mainString = @"Sean\John\\Rob\fred";
        var last = mainString.Reverse().TakeWhile(ch => '\\' != ch).Reverse();
```

It's too bad that the OP really probably asked for a string, because strings are immutable and this requires you to construct a new string instance:

```
        mainString = new string(last.ToArray());
```

Not saying I would do this, but people have been looking for an unintrusive way to do this, so... here it is

---

Now for good measure, here is the IL emitted by mono 2.8.2 C# 4.0 (dmcs) compiler in -optimize+ mode for

#### `mainString.Substring(mainString.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1)`

```
    .locals init (string  V_0)
    IL_0000:  ldstr "Sean\\John\\\\Rob\\fred"
    IL_0005:  stloc.0
    IL_0006:  ldloc.0
    IL_0007:  ldloc.0
    IL_0008:  ldc.i4.s 0x5c
    IL_000a:  callvirt instance int32 string::LastIndexOf(char)
    IL_000f:  ldc.i4.1
    IL_0010:  add
    IL_0011:  callvirt instance string string::Substring(int32)
    IL_0016:  stloc.0
```

against

#### `mainString.Reverse().TakeWhile(ch => '\\' != ch).Reverse()`

#### `mainString = new string(last.ToArray());`

```
   .locals init (string  V_0, class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<char>  V_1)
   IL_0000:  ldstr "Sean\\John\\\\Rob\\fred"
   IL_0005:  stloc.0
   IL_0006:  ldloc.0
   IL_0007:  call class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0> class [System.Core]System.Linq.Enumerable::Reverse<char> (class [mscorlib]System...
   IL_000c:  ldsfld class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<char,bool> qqq.MainClass::'<>f__am$cache0'
   IL_0011:  brtrue.s IL_0024

   IL_0013:  ldnull
   IL_0014:  ldftn bool class qqq.MainClass::'<Main>m__0'(char)
   IL_001a:  newobj instance void class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<char, bool>::'.ctor'(object, native int)
   IL_001f:  stsfld class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<char,bool> qqq.MainClass::'<>f__am$cache0'
   IL_0024:  ldsfld class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<char,bool> qqq.MainClass::'<>f__am$cache0'
   IL_0029:  call class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0> class [System.Core]System.Linq.Enumerable::TakeWhile<char> (class [mscorlib]Syst...
   IL_002e:  call class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0> class [System.Core]System.Linq.Enumerable::Reverse<char> (class [mscorlib]System...
   IL_0033:  stloc.1
   IL_0034:  ldloc.1
   IL_0035:  call !!0[] class [System.Core]System.Linq.Enumerable::ToArray<char> (class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0>)
   IL_003a:  newobj instance void string::'.ctor'(char[])
   IL_003f:  stloc.0

   //
   //
   // With the Lambda expression (ch => '\\' != ch) compiled to:
   // 
   // method line 3
   .method private static hidebysig
          default bool '<Main>m__0' (char ch)  cil managed
   {
       .custom instance void class [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::'.ctor'() =  (01 00 00 00 ) // ....

       // Method begins at RVA 0x214c
       // Code size 9 (0x9)
       .maxstack 8
       IL_0000:  ldc.i4.s 0x5c  // '\\' character
       IL_0002:  ldarg.0
       IL_0003:  ceq
       IL_0005:  ldc.i4.0
       IL_0006:  ceq
       IL_0008:  ret
   } // end of method MainClass::<Main>m__0
```

It should be clear which method is more optimized :)

Comment: While I think it's pretty cool, it is as mental as it is cool. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] strsplit=mainString.Split('\\');
string laststring = strsplit[strsplit.length-1];
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to split up strings by a character, all you need to do is `Split()` and this will return an array with all the names you need.

```
string mainString = "Sean\John\\Rob\fred";

string[] breakMe = mainString.Split('\\');

// to get the 'fred' part:
breakMe [breakMe.length-1];
```

I don't get your question with the other name ...

Comment: A string array called "break"? ;)

Comment: LOL ... I'm having a terrible day today :-/

Answer (score 1):

```
 string mainString = @"Sean\John\\Rob\fred";
    var names = mainString.Split('\\');
    lastName = names[names.Length-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] tokens = mainString.Split(new char[] { '\\' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string myString = tokens[tokens.Length - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways.

1. Go backward in the string. Start from the end and search till you find a "\".
2. Use regular expressions and specifically the lookback. Check for a word/digit (if you allow those) character preceded by a "\".

Answer (score 0):

```
string mainString = @"Sean\John\\Rob\fred";
string[] fields = mainString.Split("\\".ToCharArray());
if(fields.Length > 0) // found matches
    Console.WriteLine(fields[fields.Length-1]); // fred
```

Edit:
Depending on how your input looks like, Øyvind Knobloch-Bråthen's answer might be a better approach as it doesn't search and split the entire string, and thus is a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:-

```
 string[] names = mainString.Split(new char[]{'\\'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
 string result = names[names.Length - 1];
```